# Amazon app store and Google Play

Tags: amazon-appstore

Wondering if I publish an app on the Amazon App Store, if it will be automatically sent to the google play store as well or if I have to submit another app for the play store specifically?

Answer (score 1):

The apps stores are separate you will have to submit twice

Amazon - https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/submitting-your-app

Google - https://play.google.com/apps/publish